# EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL Linq returns VOID

Tags: linq, stored-procedures, void

I've tried Googling without any success, the only question asked wasn't didn't find a solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/linqtosql/thread/cee9df70-f38d-40be-ab1a-6697fac461d8

SP

```
@CustomerName varchar(150) = NULL

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(2000)

SET @SQL =  'SELECT A.[id], A.[startTime], N.firstName AS CustomerForename, N.surname AS CustomerSurname, O.Email AS OfficerEmail, L.Description AS Location, AT.description AS Type, ATC.description AS Category,AD.cancelledById, A.Deleted
FROM [Calendar].[dbo].[Appointments] AS A
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[Name] AS N ON A.Id = N.appointmentId 
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[Officers] AS O ON A.Officer = O.Id
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[Locations] AS L ON A.Location = L.Id
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[AppointmentTypes] AS AT ON A.Type = AT.Id
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[AppointmentTypeCategories] AS ATC ON AT.category = ATC.Id
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[AppointmentDetails] AS AD ON A.Id = AD.appointmentId
WHERE A.[id] > 1'

IF @CustomerName IS NOT NULL
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND (CustomerForename LIKE % + @CustomerName + % OR CustomerSurname LIKE % + @CustomerName + %)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

LINQ

```
public IQueryable<Appointment> GetAppointmentsBySearchCriteria(int appointmentId, string customerName, int officer, int location, int type, DateTime to, DateTime from)
{
var data = _db.GetAppointmentsBySearchCriteria(appointmentId,customerName,officer,location,type,to,from);

foreach (var appointment in data)
{

}
}
```

This is the error I receive: Cannot assign void to an implicity-typed local variable

I tried adding the following:

```
RETURN EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
RETURN
```

When the SP is dragged into the DBML I recieve the following message: The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected. Set the return type for each stored procedure

Thanks in advance for any help.

Clare :-)

Comment: I dont know if its a typo, but you need to use IS to check if CustomerName variable is null. Like **IF @CustomerName IS NOT NULL**

Comment: My next advice would be that you avoid using C# keywords as variable names in your C# code: **DateTime to, DateTime from**. I dont even think its legal plus it will only cause confusion by throwing the compiler of, such that the error messages you get may not be precise

Comment: I will change @CustomerName IS NOT NULL. I didn't realise to and from were keywords. What do they refer to?

Comment: Not sure about `to`, but `from` is a LINQ keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx

Comment: are you using Entity Framework in your LINQ ? try avoiding `to` and `from` wording by putting `DateFrom` and `DateTo`. and please also post the code snippet of `_db.GetAppointmentsBySearchCriteria()`. The immplicity-typed local variable is from EF/LINQ and nothing to do with sp_executesql

Comment: Why not let Linq create your SQL code? I think that using a stored procedure to creates inline SQL in a variable and execute it using sp_executesql is as efficient as creating the SQL in the C# code (or using Linq to SQL)

Comment: The issue isn't with the to and from wording. TURBOT: _db.GetAppointmentsBySearchCriteria - is the SP within my question
MORTB: LINQ to SQL produced incorrect joins for one table to another so I dont really want to be stepping through joins this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here appears to be the fact that if you pass in a CustomerName object, the SQL generated inside of your stored proc becomes invalid (and is subject to SQL Injection):

```
'SELECT A.[id], A.[startTime], N.firstName AS CustomerForename, N.surname AS CustomerSurname, O.Email AS OfficerEmail, L.Description AS Location, AT.description AS Type, ATC.description AS Category,AD.cancelledById, A.Deleted 
FROM [Calendar].[dbo].[Appointments] AS A 
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[Name] AS N ON A.Id = N.appointmentId  
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[Officers] AS O ON A.Officer = O.Id 
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[Locations] AS L ON A.Location = L.Id 
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[AppointmentTypes] AS AT ON A.Type = AT.Id 
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[AppointmentTypeCategories] AS ATC ON AT.category = ATC.Id 
INNER JOIN [Calendar].[dbo].[AppointmentDetails] AS AD ON A.Id = AD.appointmentId 
WHERE A.[id] > 1
 AND (CustomerForename LIKE % + @CustomerName + % OR CustomerSurname LIKE % + @CustomerName + %)'
```

CustomerForename will never be LIKE "% + @CustomerName + %". You are not passing the parameters into your sp_executeSQL call. Instead, prepend the CustomerName parameter with the % wildcards and then add the secondary where clause as follows:

```
IF @CustomerName IS NOT NULL   
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND (CustomerForename LIKE @CustomerName OR CustomerSurname LIKE @CustomerName)'
```

Then call sp_ExecuteSql as follows:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@CustomerName NVarChar(150)', @CustomerName
```

Now, you should actually get a result set from your proc. This may solve the issue with the return type not being able to be determined for the sproc.  If not, you will need to manually create a return type in the LINQ to SQL designer (or in the DBML) and then set it explicitly as the return type of the stored proc. Alternatively, you can drag the sproc from the database and drop it on your newly created type to automatically assign the return type through the designer directly.

You could also try using SqlMetal to generate the dbml as it can be better at detecting stored proc return types than the designer.

Comment: That is exactly right. This proc is invalid and Visual Studio cannot determine the return type. The OP should first run the proc outside VS to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using DBML and create the s/p manually in MS SQL Studio.
Please do the following.

1. Delete the stored procedure from the database, re-created it.
2. Run the test with your new created stored procedure in MS SQL Studio , make sure the are return data.
3. Delete the s/p from the DBML Designer, save it , recompiled, restart Visual Studio and added it again.
4. if you running into problem, Post up the screen shot and your dbml file to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you use dynamic SQL inside the stored procedure then when visual studio creates your linq objects it cant tell what type the response is. (Linq only likes to work in a strongly typed enviroment)
You can try manually changing it in visual studio which is what the error message is telling you to do;

- In visual studio, open up your DBML file into the designer view and add the SP as normal.
- Ok the error message, then select the SP's name from the list in the designer. Right click and hit properties.
- Tucked away in the properties dialog you'll find a "Return Type" that you can set manually. Experiment with that and see what you can get out of it.

However, I don't recommend it. Firstly, you'll have to do it again if you ever delete and recreate the linq object, and secondly it probably still wont give you what you want.
I would suggest you go back to the drawing board and coming up with a way of avoiding the dynamic SQL.
Take a look at [this blog entry from Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) about dynamic SQL in linq. It's a much neater solution once you get the extension methods set up.